# Workaround for Xcode closing after creating macOS app?

Tags: xcode11

I installed Xcode 11.2.1 GM seed (I heard that 11.2 was buggy). The issue is that whenever I create any type of macOS app on Xcode, it closes itself after a few seconds. I had Xcode 11.1 and I had the same issue with it too. Has anyone found a solution/workaround for this problem? By the way, my Mac is 10.14.6 and I run it on VMWare Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this issue. Weirdly, when you create a macOS app choose "None" for team option. And then the project will open without any sudden crashes.